# SOQL to Get contact details from opportunity object

Tags: apex, soql

I want to get the first primary contact details. I'm in opportunity object and trying the following query,

```
SELECT Id, Name
(SELECT name, email FROM contact)
FROM Opportunity
WHERE Opportunity.Id=:opID] ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can traverse between Opportunity and Contact thru Account.

```
Select Id, Name, Email From Contact where AccountId = :opp.AccountId
```

OR if the contact is already linked to the opportunity thru **OpportunityContactRole**, you can use it to get the contact details.

Refer this [Sales Objects ERD](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_majors.htm) to know the relationship between the common sales objects.